# How to generate Swagger with format application/json only?

Tags: shopware6

In the Swagger file by default both response formats, *JSON:API* and *application/json* are included.
This causes problems when generating Java classes and prevents the client from compiling.

I tested this with two different compilers
Swagger Code Generator 3.0.35 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen/3.0.35 as well as
OpenAPI Generator in different versions https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/3.3.4.

As a workaround the Swagger file currently has to be manually adjusted and the *JSON:API* format has to be deleted, which causes a lot of effort during updates.
Is the generation of the Swagger file possible containing only the format *application/json*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible and IMHO should also not be possible, as that would undermine the whole point of having an OpenApiSchema.

The OpenApi schema file is a specification of the shopware API, and as shopware offers both response formats it does not make sense to generate OpenApi files that are incomplete. As a specification that is not complete is by definition no specification anymore.

IMHO the issues lies with the code generators you wanna use. As they should skip formats that they don't support, instead of erroring.